# GET request doesn't work on Intel XDK

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, intel-xdk, get-request

I want to use GET request after barcode scanner but it doesnt work. Also it doesn't appear any error. My code is in below.

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function (result) {
  console.log(fName, "Scanned result found!");
  $.get("http://example.com/qr.php?id=" + result.text, function(data) {
    console.log(data); //Success
  });
}, function (error) {
  alert("Error: " + error);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the issue is with the IntelXDK and not because you're sending a cross domain AJAX request?

Comment: Actually, I don't know. I'm new on this. I was use request like that in web and it worked.

Comment: Does `console.log(fName, "Scanned result found!");` appear?

Comment: No it doesnt appear